# Calculate the effective linear attenuation coefficient of a megavoltage multi-energetic beam

Tags: radiation

Are you aware of a method or source for calculating the effective linear attenuation coefficient,$\mu_\text{eff}$, of a megavoltage multi-energetic beam ? For a mono-energetic beam one could use the half-value layer (HVL) formula $\mu = \frac{\ln 2}{\text{HVL}}$.

Does it make sense to consider individual energy levels and their attenuation coefficient and get an average value? Like:

\begin{align*}
\mu_\text{eff} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=1}^{N}\mu_j = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=1}^{N}\frac{\ln 2}{\text{HVL}_j}
\end{align*}

On second thoughts this doesn't seem right, because it doesn't take into account the contribution of each mono-energetic "sub-beam" (so to speak) to the multi-energetic "total-beam".

It should be more like:

\begin{align*}
\mu_\text{eff} = \sum_j w_j \mu_j
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The impact of beam hardening makes most of these attempts at "exact" (closed form) calculations very difficult. High energy radiation scatters - this takes it out of the "forward" beam but it continues "broadly in the same direction" and may even scatter back in the forward direction. You need to keep this is mind when you analyze the problem.

Typically you are right that you would want to analyze as a weighted series of (quasi) mono-energetic beams - but do take the above into consideration. It may be that a full Monte Carlo simulation is the way to go. There are several very good tools for this in the public domain.

Bottom line: as the beam progresses through layers of shielding, "beam hardening" will occur which will affect the "effective mu". So there is no single simple constant - the best you can hope for is $\mu_{eff}(x)$ - effective mu as a function of depth for a given initial spectrum and shielding material.